# Make the next sibling push on a relative positioned element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a small question.
What would be the best way to make a sibling push on the last element of said div?
this is the structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="formContainer col-lg-6">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                ...content....
                <button>Submit Form</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="datePicker">
       calendar where user picks dates
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS (more or less)

```
form > button {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    right: -54%;
}
```

Here is an image as an example:
[image]

I want the right col-6 div to push on the save button which is in the left col-6, because there are elements of the rightmost div that are being added that start overlapping. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: Why does the button need to stay there? Your calendar is part of the form. It seems more reasonable to have a form element that wraps both columns and Save button sits below both of them.

Comment: It's the `right:-54%` that's dragging it to the right. It applies to all the `button`s in any `form` on your page. I'd say your selector is a tad too general. Why not use `text-center` class on the column for centering the button?

Comment: the button is there because the owner wants it there :( I have to keep it between the divs. The calendar has its own logic that gets sent to a different server. Don't ask me why, I inherited this heh. I'll still try putting it into the form though

Comment: honestly, the css here is convoluted as its wrapped in col-8 offset-4 rows and its a pain to do even the smallest changes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="formContainer col-lg-6">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                ...content....
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="datePicker">
       calendar where user picks dates
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
       <button class="btn btn-default"
               onclick="$('.formContainer form', $(this).closest('.row')).submit();">Submit Form</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I moved the button in a new column and I'm using inline Javascript to submit the form when it's pressed.

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm :) I appreciate it a lot!